# What is the correct way to use db values in code

Tags: java, database, database-design, constants

I've in a lot of places in my code hard coded comparing and I'm not happy with that. I'm looking for the correct way to approach this.

**EXAMPLE**

```
public class Status {
  public static final int ACTIVE = 1,
                        INACTIVE = 2,
                           ENDED = 3,
                          PAUSED = 4,
                             NEW = 5,
                            INIT = 6,
                         STARTED = 7;

  private int id;
  private String name;

  public int getId(){ return this.id; }
  public String getName(){ return this.name; }

  //get and set the object from the db by the id
  public Status(int id){}
}

public class Job {
  private int id;
  private Status stage;

  //get and set the object from the db by the id
  Job(int id){}

  public boolean isStageStatusEnded(){
    return this.stage.getId() == Status.ENDED;
  }
}
```

I've this DB table:

```
mysql> desc statuses;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select * from statuses;
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | ACTIVE   |
|  2 | INACTIVE |
|  3 | ENDED    |
|  4 | PAUSED   |
|  5 | NEW      |
|  6 | INIT     |
|  7 | STARTED  |
+----+----------+
```

As you can see the `static final int` in `Status` class is exact copy of the table `statuses` and that for the `return this.stage.getId() == Status.ENDED;` line. Now if in any time the values will change(`id`/`name`) i'll have to change the `static int`'s as well. I dont see how can I change it but if you know a way - share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several ways. This can be one of them:

1. Drop the `final` keyword from your constants.
2. On start the application, query to the database for the current values.
3. Populate the values in the constants with Java reflection.

   ```
   Field field = Status.class.getDeclaredField(name);
   field.setInt(field, id);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You'll still have to keep these values hardcoded somewhere, either in the database or in the code cause otherwise you will simply not know what each value stands for. After that you can either persist them to the DB if that suits your needs or load into your app.

As Paul wrote, you'd load the values from DB when your application starts, but I suggest using a `enum` instead of a number of `int` constants which may save a lot of nerve.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809130/) is a link you may find useful and as for enums over constants, read J.Bloch, Effective Java.